# Spring - Quartz no execute jobclass

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to run a job with quartz and spring but does not run the job and not get error on the console. The job is saved in mysql but it not runs.

my configuration is

- spring 4.0.6
- quartz 2.2.1

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="scheduler" name="scheduler"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean"
    scope="singleton">
    <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">MyClusteredScheduler</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">QRTZ_</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval">20000</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold">60000</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
    <property name="username" value="*****" />
    <property name="password" value="*****" />
</bean>
```

The MyJob class

```
public class MyJob implements Job, Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1750295779628942902L;

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("run job run!!!");
    }
}
```

the main test class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    StdScheduler stdScheduler= (StdScheduler) context.getBean("scheduler");
    MyJob myJob= (MyJob) context.getBean("myJob");
    try {
        JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(MyJob.class).withIdentity("triggerUno10").build();  
        Trigger trigger= TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("triggerUno10").withSchedule(
                                    CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?")).forJob(jobDetail).build(); 
        stdScheduler.start();
        stdScheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the quartz version somehow does not work well with spring4.0.6, to fix that I've downgraded quartz to 2.1.7 and it worked.